# Android how to move scrollview child to top programatically

Tags: android

I have a `ScrollView` which contains numerous views on `LinearLayout`.I have implemented `expand` and `collapse` layouts. `OnClick` of view,it either expand or collapse.So when a view expands,I want to programmatically  move `ScrollView` such that the view comes on top of the screen.See image below

[image]

I want to move the `ScrollView` to the length shown on red line. The `child` of `ScrollView` contains a `TextView`(4:Status bar notification) and an `ImageView`.Further `ScrollView` may or maynot contains views above or below the `TextView ImageView` combination. I have used a CustomScrollView where I findout `scroll Y` by

```
public int newY=0;
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int X, int Y, int oldX, int oldY) {
    super.onScrollChanged(X, Y, oldX, oldY);
    this.newY=Y;
}
```

For that I have used following logic

```
 public void translateView(View view){
    int[] xy =new int[2];
   //view = ImageView
    view.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    int scrollY = xy[1]+view.getBottom();
    //screenHeight =ScreenHeight of the phone
    if(scrollY>screenHeight){
      //heading textView
        textView.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
        int diff = screenHeight-xy[1];
        diff =Math.abs(diff);
        int moveHeight = (int) (scrollView.newY+diff);
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, moveHeight);

    }
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is finding the difference between `y` position of `TextView` and subtracting it with screen height and scrolling the `ScrollView` to those difference,so that the view is shown on top.But it is not working.Any Idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what I was doing wrong. Each screen comprises of `StatusBar` and in my case `ActionBar`.So when I was calculating the `View Y` position,I was calculating from top of the screen and whenever I use the increment value for `ScrollView Scroll`,I was moving my view to top of the screen.So the actual solution would be

```
public void translateView(final View view){
    int[] xy =new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    int scrollY = xy[1]+view.getBottom();


    if(scrollY>DataHolder.screenHeight){
        handle.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
        int actualY=xy[1]-DataHolder.actionbarHeight-DataHolder.statusBarHeight;
        int moveHeight = (int) (scrollView.newY+actualY);
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, moveHeight);   
    }
}
```

So by doing this my view automatically reaches the top of the screen